# How to paint outside of paintComponent?

Tags: java, java-2d, graphics2d, paintcomponent

I have a canvas that is drawing everything in a `paintComponent()` method.

Is it possible to draw outside of `paintComponent` (without calling a method within `paintComponent`?)

If so how do you go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you mean and why you need it.  For example, it is *possible* to create a `BufferedImage`, get the `Graphics2D` object, `Graphics.paint()` everything that should be on the image, then drop the image into a `JLabel`.

But since I do not know what you are trying to *achieve* (as opposed to what you are trying to *do*) I cannot know if that answer solves the unstated problem.

Answer (score -1):

I found out how to solve this issue.

What I did was make JPanel an inner class to my JFrame class.

In JPanels paintComponent I had it calling a method from the outer class which did some updating of the graphics, by passing paintComponents Graphics2D object.

This has allowed me to paint "outside" of paintComponent, just as I needed.

Comment: You should NEVER do this. All painting code should be contained in the  The paintComponent() method or a child method that is invoked by the paintComponent() method. You should NEVER invoke this child method directly. If you think you need to do this then you have a wrong design for your program.